# WatchKit Moving SpriteNode with WKCrownDelegate

Tags: iphone, swift, watchkit, skspritenode, watchos-3

I am using the WatchKit framework, and using the class WKCrownDelegate. I am trying to move my spriteNode Named "PLAYER" in x direction using the Digital Crown of the Apple Watch. in the console I see my Digital Crown Working and Presenting me with print numbers regarding which direction I'm scrolling but my spriteNode is not moving.

Comment: Please include some code in the question. It's very difficult to tell what's not working for you without any code.

Comment: I would like to know a way to move a SKSpriteNode in SpriteKit Watch Game Using WKCrownDelegate. either in Y direction or X direction. thank you